# C++ how to access struct in struct

Tags: c++, struct

I got a question about structs.. C++ is not language what I'm learning but I have a need to do exercise..

I have a struct like this:

```
struct List
{
    int data;
    List* next;
};
```

and I got class and methods with which I can add/remove/printout elements of the struct so for example to view elements I got method:

```
void Kopa::Print()
{
    List *tmp = p;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp.struktura;
}
```

The question is, how can I add and access new struct in **List** struct?
I guess it the struct will look smth like this but I don't understand how to access it with class methods..

```
struct List
{
    int data;
    List* next;

    struct NewList
    {
        int data;
        NewList* next;
    };
};
```

Comment: that's a useless struct *declaration*, you don't have an actual member variable.

Comment: I don't understand your question. How can you access `List::NewList`? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Are you sure that the first declaration you wrote is not everything you need?

Comment: please first tell us *what* you want to do, and not *how* you want to do it.

Comment: Is is possible you are confused about the difference between static types and runtime objects?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to declare a *member* of that structure, just like you declare other member variables:

```
struct List
{
    struct NewList
    {
        int data;
    };

    NewList my_new_list;  // Declare a member
};
```

Then you use it like any other member, just nest the member access as needed:

```
List l;
l.my_new_list.data = ...;
```

---

If you mean how to access the `NewList` structure inside `List` to declare a local variable, then you have to use the scope operator `::`:

```
List::NewList new_list;
new_list.data = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an implementation assignment for linked list

Your struct looks like a node struct, not a list.  So I will be using struct Node instead of List to avoid confusion.

I don't know where your p comes from, but it is essentially how you would create p in your function.

```
Node *p = new Node();
p->data = 1;
p->next = NULL;
```

now if you need to add a new one, do the same thing

```
Node *q = new Node ();
q->data = 2;
q->next = NULL;
//assign q after p
p->next = q;
```

You can also create a constructor in your struct

```
Node (Node *previous, int newData)
{
    List *q = new Node ();
    q->data = newData;
    q->next = NULL;
    previous->next = q;
}
```

make sure you call delete to clean up these pointers when you are done with them